# Xcode 14 Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, xcode14

In **Xcode 14** after adding the **Widget** target we are facing the below issue while **Archive** the build.

> error: Build input file cannot be found:
> '/Users/ramprasathselvam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-hblrdkreixdjltdnvjrxmvejbzjs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/CCCC/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/XXWidgetExtension.appex/XXWidgetExtension'.
> Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'XXWidgetExtension' from project 'XXXX')'

Comment: hi, did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `i386` in `Excluded Architectures` under the `build setting` in both (App and widget) targets.

App target
[image]

Widget target
[image]

After adding the **i386** in **Excluded Architectures** this issue is resolved for myself.